# MacBook Pro strange white screen upon rebooting mouse and trackpad not working

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad

My MacBook Pro 2016 keyboard and trackpad is not working but the Touch Bar is works fine.

The below images show what’s showing up when starting:

[image]

[image]

The only similar problem that I found on the net is found at the below fixit post:
https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/237198/MacBook+Air+boots+to+strange+screen+-+What+should+I+do

It was working fine yesterday. but then I went to school in the morning and when I opened it the mouse and keyboard wasn’t working and it had a screen talking about connecting or setting up an external keyboard or mouse.

I rebooted it thinking that would get it working and am now stuck here at the screens seen in the images above.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I ask if you have access to an external USB keyboard and/or mouse?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is reset the NVRAM.

**Resetting the NVRAM**

Your Mac uses Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM). To reset the NVRAM on your MacBook Pro model follow these steps:

1. **Fully shut down your machine.**
2. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* immediately press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.
3. Keep these keys pressed down for **at least 20 seconds!**
4. Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.

**Note:**Assuming this resolves the issue and you can log back in fine, you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone information, etc).

If you still have problems after doing this, let me know.